# how to use overloaded functions with union types?

Tags: typescript

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false&noImplicitThis=false&noImplicitReturns=false&alwaysStrict=false&esModuleInterop=false&declaration=false&target=99&jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwBQEoBciwgLYBGApgE6IA+iAzlCTGMogN4BQi7iJRUIJSADAG4WAXxYtQkWAkTBUAB2y5CpLIgIxk9KMMnR4SOYuq16yNQThwANkQCGYXeH0yjS-MTKUadBhc3aFOpWtg7MbBxcPHyIqFAAnvJEcMCI8ogAvFmIAOTKnjnoiAD8iABCmgCSYFCo-EXYwHbWVETCYhLO0kh4dvQY2ABucDAAJuEciBAINGnuKl4mvowZKBjCEezTYLNgcFAA6nAkANZmmbIK6MKTtlCIAO7HZww3HFQPMFAQABaxCUkUmkiqxJpMIHZWrl8qQcphNmDJk9TudVkZrgjEVsZvdkS9kAA5DykbAaLQ1C7ojZYsHbKg2IgAOmscDQeLMjKgcAAMnAIbYAMqmBgYDE08EzBnM1modkMIkLTk8vnNIhC5ait7iqaS2zStB7Q7PDlc3n8tXCtDoMXa9RcOwnalYiFQnI+MxwzFYuUrS7yG3aum440MdVmUkhexINFXJ2B3VMllskPIRmDZogIgAeTk1q14rpUqTspTYYYaYz2dzAYLCf1qENRxR5fT1kzOc1XsRBHtjoRYjEQA)

I'm trying to understand how to integrate an overloaded function in my codebase.
The example is a bit contrived, but I've tried to simplify my usecase and create a minimal case.

I have a function `g` that return a union of two types (in the example, `g` may return a `number` or a `string`).

I also have a function `f`. This function requires a parameter that is the same union, and have a return type that depends on the input type. (in the example, `f(number)` returns a `bigint`, while `f(string)` returns a `boolean`)

Finally, I have a `main` function that basically should

- call `g` to have a value `p` that may be a `number` of a `string`
- call `f(p)` to have a value `notWorking` that may be a `bigint` or a `boolean`, dependent on `p`
- have a check on the type of `p`, with some additional logic on the `notWorking` value

I would really like to call `f(p)` before the `switch`, but it seems that the only way I can make a working solution is to call `f(p)` inside all the "branches" of the `switch`.

```js
function g(): number | string {
    return 0;
}

function f(p: number): bigint;
function f(p: string): boolean;
function f(p: number | string): bigint | boolean {
    return (typeof p === 'number') ? BigInt(0) : false;
}

function main(): void {
    const p: number | string = g();

    const notWorking = f(p);
    let working;
    switch (typeof p) {
        case 'number':
            working = f(p);
            const workingNumber: bigint = f(p);

            console.log(working.toLocaleString());
            console.log(workingNumber.toLocaleString());
            console.log(notWorking.toLocaleString());
            break;

        case 'string':
            working = f(p);
            const workingString: boolean = f(p);

            console.log(working.valueOf());
            console.log(workingString.valueOf());
            console.log(notWorking.valueOf());
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Overloads for specific elements of a union are useful for situations where the specific type of the argument being provided is known at compile-time for whatever reason (for instance, because it's a literal [`f("23")`], it comes from a variable or property with one of those specific types, or because it's been narrowed from something broader [like a union] by some kind of type guard). So for instance, where it's clear at compile time that `f`'s argument is a `string`, or it's clear that it's a `number`.

In your case, it's not always clear; sometimes, the type of the argument is still `string | number` (such as your first call to `f` in `main`), which means neither your `f(string)` nor `f(number)` overload signature applies to it because it's `string | number` rather than being either of those. If you need to also support that case, add a third overload signature covering it (since the [implementation signature is not exposed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature) unless you expose it as an overload signature):

```typescript
function f(p: number): bigint;
function f(p: string): boolean;
function f(p: number | string): bigint | boolean;  // <============
function f(p: number | string): bigint | boolean {
    return (typeof p === 'number') ? BigInt(0) : false;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false&noImplicitThis=false&noImplicitReturns=false&alwaysStrict=false&esModuleInterop=false&declaration=false&target=99&jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwBQEoBciwgLYBGApgE6IA+iAzlCTGMogN4BQi7iJRUIJSADAG4WAXxYtQkWAkTBUAB2y5CpLIgIxk9KMMnR4SOYuq16yNQThwANkQCGYXeH0yjS-MTKUadBhc3aFOpWtg5OUgayCu4qXia+5tgaWmBQQZY29kisHJzcvEioUACe8kRwwIjyiAC8dYgA5MqeDeiIAPyIAEKaAJKpqPxt2MB21lREwmISztJIeHb0GNgAbnAwACbMbBwQCDRVMZ5BPma1KBjCO+x7YAdgcFAA6nAkANZnNVHy6MK5tmkAO6vD4MP4cKiAmBQCAAC0QRVK5UqP22uVyEDsE0azVIDUw13RuWB70+31+hKJN32QJBZgAch5SEkAqlzkYKZSqbcqJkAHTWOBoEmg5B8qBwAAycExtgAyqYGBgKVT0Tz+YLhXSGIzYuKpTKxkQFQlleDVdS7hqhagHs9tWKJdLZcbFWh0CqLewCFw7G8rqrMdiGqcGPiuUSRWSOeaLTzaaSGCazEkQll2QpOV7LbzbAKbVGGHyVmMQEQAPJyD2xwP7a1axPIZNFkvWMuVs0RtV1vOa22PF6N4ulitVz1en32f2EsRiIA)

That still supports the cases where the specific type (`string` or `number`, not `string | number`) is known at compile time, but *also* supports the case where all that's known is that it's `string | number`.

Comment: but then the type of `notWorking` is `bigint | boolean`. And is still an union type even in the branches of the `switch`. It's not like the type of `notWorking` is `bigint` in the first case and `boolean` in the second one.

Comment: @VitoDeTullio - Yes, it is. Unless you narrow the type of the `string | number` you'll use as an argument *prior* to the call to `f` (for instance, with your `switch`), there is **no way** for TypeScript to help you know the type of `f`'s result more precisely than `bigint | boolean`. (You can, of course, then do a type guard on that result to narrow it.)

Comment: yeah... my hope is to be able to tell that the type of `notWorking` is dependant of the type of `p`, so a guard on `p` can change the inferred type of `notWorking`

Comment: @VitoDeTullio - TypeScript can do that, but only if it knows that the type of `p` in `f(p)` is, specifically, `string` or that it's specifically `number`, not if it's `string | number`. That's why your `workingNumber` and `workingString` work, but it can't work if you call `f(p)` when the type of `p` is still the union. (And it won't narrow the type of one variable based on the type of another, even if we programmers can see that it would be valid to do so. TypeScript's narrowing only goes so far.)